# Which similarity measures are immune to word transpositions?

Tags: similarity

I am looking for similarity measures to compare phrases with potentially transposed words, for example "extended amounts" and "amounts extended".
The ones I tried already punish those transpositions too much for my purposes. Is there a string similarity function that does not punish or only slightly punishes those transpositions or can I only satisfyingly solve this use case by doing tokenization and calculating individual similarities over the tokens?

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.*;

public class SimilarityTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String original = "amounts extended";
        String transposed = "extended amounts";
        StringDistance[] distances =
        {new NGramDistance(),new JaroWinklerDistance(),new LevensteinDistance()};

        for(StringDistance dist: distances) System.out.println(String.format("%18s",dist)+" "+dist.getDistance(original, transposed));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
        ngram(2) 0.125
jarowinkler(0.7) 0.5416667
      levenstein 0.125
```

Comment: P.S.: I used Java with the Lucene similarity measures for the example but I am not including them as tags because similarity functions implemented in different libraries or languages are fine for me as answers.

Comment: You can split strings by words, sort them, and then compare results.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou That's what I meant with tokenization but I wanted to know if this behaviour is inherent in some similarity function. Also sorting would not work when terms are missing, e.g. "amounts before extension" and "amounts extended" (before would be compared to extended). I assume this is similar to the stable marriage / hospital matching CS problems.

Comment: I mean compare whole strings, combined from sorted words, not words themselves.

Comment: I guess this would work in most cases but not when the first letter is changed (e.g. "cambodia" vs "kambodia").

Comment: I used this particular approach in one of our projects, it works pretty well. Good side effect is that input string becomes cleared from non-letter characters thus making it easier to proceed.

Comment: yes, I see the issue of misspelled first letter...

Comment: On the other hand I guess this first letter misspelling doesn't occur very often especially if it works in your project so I will definitely try out your approach, thanks!

Comment: First letter is misspelled rarely, because first and last letters of a word are  "anchors" for human eye

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it fits your purpose, since you didn't specify it, and it's not a distance *per se*, but you should check if you can use a [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

To implement a distance measure, you can either combine it with machine learning techniques, or, if your inputs are small, possibly compute string distances between each pair of words and solve the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) (see [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm))